# singularities of the function $f(z)=z^{n}\sin\left ( \frac{1}{z} \right )$ $n\in \mathbb{N}-{0}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

$$\require{cancel}$$
I want to study the singularities of the function

> $$f(z)=z^{n}\sin\left ( \frac{1}{z} \right )$$ for $$n\in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$$
>   and  $$z\in \mathbb{C}$$

I don't understand how to grasp that the function has a essential singularity in $$z=0$$

From real analysis I remember that $$\lim_{x\to0}x^{n}\sin\left ( \frac{1}{x} \right )=0$$

I know that for essential singularities in $$z=z_{k}$$ $$\lim_{z\to z_{z}}\left | f(z) \right |=\cancel{\exists}$$

Where is the mistake or the contradiction?
What about the residue?

Thank u so much.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ can be considered a subspace of $\mathbb C$ but convergence in a bigger space is always harder to achieve than in the smaller subspace. When you look only at a small part of a function it might seem to converge, but approaching it from other directions (which are only accesible in the bigger space) might reveal that it is actually not convergent in this context.

Comment: You is $Sin(x)=\sin(x)$ ... I mean sine of $x$? You should write it with small letters, one might think that this is another function.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} x^n\sin(\frac{1}{x}) = 0$ only holds for real $x$ since the sine function is bounded over $\mathbb R$, but over $\mathbb C$ it grows exponentially in direction of the imaginary axis.

Answer (score 1):

If the singularity would be non-essential, the function $f(z)=z^m\sin \frac{1}{z}$ would be holomorphic for $m$ large enough. But this contradicts the identity theorem, because this function has infinitely many zeros in any neighborhood of $0$, because $f\Bigg(\cfrac{1}{\pi l}\Bigg)=0$ for any $l \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

**First** Calculate over $\mathbb R$
$$
\lim_{y \to 0 \\ y\in \mathbb R} (iy)^n \sin(\frac{1}{iy})
$$
that is the limit over the imaginary axix, to see why your limit doesn't exist.

**The singularity**
You know that 
$$\sin(z)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

This is true for all $z \in \mathbb C$.

If $x \neq 0$ setting $z=\frac{1}{x}$ (which we can because we know the above relation holds for ALL $z$) you get

$$\sin(\frac{1}{x})= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{x^{2k+1}(2k+1)!}$$

Therefore, 
$$f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{n-2k-1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

if you split this series in the Taylor part ($n-2k-1\geq0$) and the negative Laurent part ($n-2k-1 <0$) you see why you have an essential singularity.

The residue is given by the coefficient of $x^{-1}$ which can be read from the series.